# Knockoutjs combine text binding with another element

Tags: knockout.js

I want to put inner text and another element into one .
Currently I'm doing:

```
function menuItem(number, text) {
        this.text = text;
        this.html = '<span><font class="small">' + number + '.</font>' + text + '</span>';
    }

    function viewModelMenu() {
        // Data
        var self = this;
        self.menuItems = [new menuItem('1', 'First'),
            new menuItem('2', 'Second')];
}
```

and view:

```
<div data-bind="html:$data.html"></div>
```

But html encode isn't [safe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html)?

Can i build text using knockout text binding or anything else?

Comment: Well, it isn't. What exactly is your problem??

Comment: i wondering how to get same markup without html binding?

Comment: You can't. It isn't safe but that does not mean you should not use it. :) You only have to be careful, for example the HTML should not depend on user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments mention you can't do this without the html binding and you really shouldn't since it's unsafe. What's wrong with adding a little extra markup to your menu item template

```
<div>
    <span>
        <font class="small" data-bind="text: number"></font>
        <span data-bind="text: text"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

It's safe, it can be easily made to look the same and if the number is observable and changes it won't re-render the whole item.

Hope this helps.